# Creating a message driven inbound channel adapter to connect to Kafka using Spring integration java configuration

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

Java code to create a kafka consumer using spring integration java dsl

Comment: Hi there! Welcome aboard StackOverflow, please can you state/ elaborate the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I just wanted to share this code which i felt should be helpful for others so i posted this question & answered it myself. Thanks for replying @robot_alien

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code to create a  message driven adapter to connect to consume message from kafka

```
@Value("${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}")
private String bootstrapServers;
@Value("${spring.kafka.topic}")
private String springIntegrationKafkaTopic;
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow kafkaReader() throws Exception {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Kafka.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(listener(),ListenerMode.record))
            .channel("queureader")
            .get();
}

@Bean
public KafkaMessageListenerContainer listener() {
    return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer(consumerFactory(), new ContainerProperties(this.springIntegrationKafkaTopic));
}

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, this.bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "kafkaListener");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(props);
}


@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "queureader")
public void Print(Message<?> msg)  {

    System.out.println(msg.getPayload().toString());
}
```

---

In application.properties

- spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers = We need to mention the server name
  -spring.kafka.topic= Name of the topic

You can mention any value for ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG.